# Почему if внутри функции не работает корректно?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Пытаюсь внутри функции определить, выходит ли значение из строки фрейма за пределы доверительного интервала:

```
def checking(row):
  flag=False #переменная, показывающая, является ли строка аномалией
  for i in range(32):#пробегаемся по значению в каждом столбце
    a=row[i]
    b=np.mean(df[columns[i]])-3*np.std(df[columns[i]])
    c=np.mean(df[columns[i]])+3*np.std(df[columns[i]])
    if (a<b) or (a>c):
      flag=True
  return flag
```

Когда отлаживаю функцию с помощью print(), то все выводится корректно:

```
def checking(row):
  flag=False #переменная, показывающая, является ли строка аномалией
  for i in range(32):#пробегаемся по значению в каждом столбце
    a=row[i]
    b=np.mean(df[columns[i]])-3*np.std(df[columns[i]])
    c=np.mean(df[columns[i]])+3*np.std(df[columns[i]])
    print((a<b) or (a>c))
```

Результат:

```
False
False
True
False
False
False
False
False
```

Но как только подставляю выражение в условие, то значение флага всегда становится true:

```
def checking(row):
  flag=False #переменная, показывающая, является ли строка аномалией
  for i in range(32):#пробегаемся по значению в каждом столбце
    a=row[i]
    b=np.mean(df[columns[i]])-3*np.std(df[columns[i]])
    c=np.mean(df[columns[i]])+3*np.std(df[columns[i]])
    #print((a<b) or (a>c))
    if (a<b) or (a>c):
      flag=True
    print(flag)
  return flag
```

Результат:

```
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
```

Не понимаю, почему так происходит. Код запускаю в Google Colaboratory.

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе [mcve] входных данных (__в виде текста / CSV / Python кода или ссылки на файл__) и __то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе__. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: @Интик разве значение флага не меняется на false при повторном вызове функции? Просто суть в том, что через эту функцию проходит строка датафрейма, и если в ее столбцах встречается хоть одна аномалия, то флаг меняется на True и дальше не меняется, независимо от результата проверки следующих ячеек строки. Если дописать в этом цикле else: false, то сохранится результат проверки **только последнего столбца**.

Answer (score 4):

Пример данных:

```
In [132]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(5, size=(15, 2)), columns=list("ab"))

In [133]: df.loc[2, "a"] = 100

In [134]: df
Out[134]:
      a  b
0     3  4
1     2  4
2   100  1
3     2  2
4     2  4
5     3  2
6     4  1
7     3  1
8     3  4
9     0  3
10    1  4
11    3  0
12    0  2
13    2  1
14    3  3
```

векторизированное решение:

```
def check(col, n=3):
    return (col - col.mean()).abs() > n * col.std()

res = df.apply(check, n=3)
```

результат:

```
In [136]: res
Out[136]:
        a      b
0   False  False
1   False  False
2    True  False
3   False  False
4   False  False
5   False  False
6   False  False
7   False  False
8   False  False
9   False  False
10  False  False
11  False  False
12  False  False
13  False  False
14  False  False
```